# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager and dynamic row height

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to create something like this in RecyclerView:

[image: Expected Output]

But, I am getting this:

[image: Actual Output]

Is there a way to make it happen with RecyclerView?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post your code for java and xml files here

Comment: @mdb_5203 posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try & check replacing your line

```
postLine.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2));
```

with

```
postLine.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Answer (score 0):

init :

```
postLine.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
postLine.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2));
```

The function that prepares the post to add them in recyclerView

```
private void preparePosts(JSONArray posts){  
    listOfLine1.clear(); //SparseArray  
    listOfLine2.clear(); //SparseArray  
    postLine.removeAllViews(); //RecyclerView 
    postList.clear(); //ListArray<Post> postList 
    int postline2h = 0;
    int postline1h = 0;

    try{
        Post ps;
        for(int i = 0; i<posts.length();i++){
            ps = new Post(posts.getJSONObject(i));
            if(postline1h>postline2h){
                listOfLine2.put(listOfLine2.size(),ps);
                postline2h += ps.getHeight();
            }else{
                postline1h += ps.getHeight();
                listOfLine1.put(listOfLine1.size(),ps);
            }
        }

        int i =0;
        boolean firstnull,secondnull;
        while (i!=listOfLine2.size()-1 || i!=listOfLine1.size()-1){
            if(listOfLine1.get(i)!=null){
                firstnull = false;
                postList.add(listOfLine1.get(i));
                listOfLine1.remove(i);
            }else firstnull = true;

            if(listOfLine2.get(i)!=null){
                secondnull = false;
                postList.add(listOfLine2.get(i));
                listOfLine2.remove(i);
            }else secondnull = true;

            if(secondnull && firstnull) break;
            i++;
        }
        postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }catch (Exception e){
        log(e);
    }
}}
```

Adapter:

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsHolder> {
   private ArrayList<Post> posts;
   public PostsAdapter(ArrayList<Post> postslist){
      posts = postslist;
   }
   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return posts.size();
   }
   @Override
   public PostsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       return new PostsHolder(new LinearLayout(parent.getContext()));
   }
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(PostsHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.setPost(posts.get(position));
  }
   @Override
   public void onViewRecycled(PostsHolder holder) {
      super.onViewRecycled(holder);
      holder.getPost().die();
   }
}
```

onBindViewHolder post.setPost is going to add the views to the Layout